# How to merge cells vertically

Tags: tables

Is it possible to create a table like this one?

[image]

The usual structure of tables I use looks like this:

```
\begin{table}[H]
    \begin{adjustbox}{width=\textwidth,center}
    % \begin{adjustbox}{center}
        \begin{tabular}{lll}
            \hline
            \multicolumn{1}{l}{\head{XXX}} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\head{XXX}} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\head{XXX}} \\
            \hline
            \ttfamily xxx & \ttfamily xxx & \ttfamily xxx \\
            \hline
        \end{tabular}
    \end{adjustbox}
    \vspace{ - 05 mm}
    \caption{xxx}
    \label{tab:xxx}
\end{table}
```

Answer (score 111, accepted):

You can use `multirow` If you are trying to align four rows of a particular column, put

```
\multirow{4}{*}{XXX}
```

in the first row and leave three subsequent rows below empty like

```
\multirow{4}{*}{XXX} &
                     &
                     &
                     &
```

Then the contents are vertically aligned.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
\centering
%     \begin{adjustbox}{width=\textwidth,center}
    % \begin{adjustbox}{center}
        \begin{tabular}{lll}
            \hline
            \multirow{4}{*}{XXX} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{XXX} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{XXX} \\\cline{2-3}
                                 & \multicolumn{1}{l}{XXX} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{XXX} \\\cline{2-3}
                                 & \multicolumn{1}{l}{XXX} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{XXX} \\\cline{2-3}
                                 & \multicolumn{1}{l}{XXX} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{XXX} \\\hline
            \ttfamily xxx & \ttfamily xxx & \ttfamily xxx \\                \hline
        \end{tabular}
%     \end{adjustbox}
%     \vspace{ - 05 mm}
    \caption{xxx}
    \label{tab:xxx}
\end{table}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How can I do it with the TexStudio tables wizard?

Comment: what exactly does the asterisk do there?

Comment: As far as I can tell, the width of the column is specified at where the asterisk is put and the asterisk itself is used if the width should be automatically inherited from the data in the columns (https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/73283/how-to-use-multirow)

Answer (score 10):

You can use `\multirow` to do this!

```
\multirow{<number of rows>}{<width>}{<text>}
```

Make sure to include `\usepackage{multirow}` at the top.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a stripped down version of what you want (I had to get rid of a few things because I didn't know which packages you had loaded and the code wouldn't compile without them):

```
\begin{table}[h]
        \begin{tabular}{lll}
            \hline
            \multicolumn{1}{l}{XXX} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{XXX} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{XXX} \\\cline{2-3}
             \ttfamily xxx & \ttfamily xxx & \ttfamily xxx \\
            \hline
        \end{tabular}
    \vspace{ -05mm}
    \caption{xxx}
    \label{tab:xxx}
\end{table}
```

In summary, what you need is the command `\cline{2-3}` at the end of a line to indicate where the line should start and finish (in this case it starts at column 2 and finishes at column 3).

Comment: OK. I think I got it. But how to align the left-hand side element to the centre?

Comment: Align it vertically to the centre you mean? This construct doesn't give a way to do that. I think you can tweak it to give the result you want, but in the example you gave this doesn't even make sense. I suggest you give a better example in your question (more rows so that alignment is an issue), but to be honest, I am pretty sure there is a way to actually merge the cells, instead of just dealing with the lines, I just don't know it.