# How to use \multirow

Tags: tables, multirow

I can compile this table separately but when I want to compile the whole file, it gives me an error, which is fixed by removing `\multirow`.

```
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{table}[htbp]
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|p{1cm}p{1cm}p{1cm}p{1cm}p{1cm}p{1cm}p{1cm}|}
\hline
A & B & C & D & \multicolumn{7}{|c|}{F}  \\ \hline
\multirow{ 2}{}{1} & 0 & 6 & 230 & 35 & 40 & 55 & 25 & 40 & 35 & \\
& 1 & 5 & 195 & 25 & 50 & 35 & 40 & 45 &  &  \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\label{table2}
\end{table}
```

Answer (score 222, accepted):

There are some errors in your code; you need to give a second argument to `\multirow` (an explicit value for the cell width or `*` to use the natural width of the contents); also, `\label` must always appear *after* `\caption` in floating environments:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|p{1cm}p{1cm}p{1cm}p{1cm}p{1cm}p{1cm}p{1cm}|}
\hline
A & B & C & D & \multicolumn{7}{|c|}{F}  \\ \hline
\multirow{ 2}{*}{1} & 0 & 6 & 230 & 35 & 40 & 55 & 25 & 40 & 35 & \\
& 1 & 5 & 195 & 25 & 50 & 35 & 40 & 45 &  &  \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{A test caption}
\label{table2}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

It is not clear why you are using `p{...}` columns if the cells are not containing paragraphs.

As a side note, I used `\centering` instead of the `center` environment to avoid adding extra vertical spacing (which in most cases is not desired).

You are not using all the columns you declared, but I guess that this was just for the example.

Comment: Source for [multirow](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/multirow)

Comment: Note the need for using [\cline{2-10}](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/8555/61946) if you want a horizontal line between rows 2 and 3.

Comment: @Gonzalo Medina In the table environment in the example code, the '\' character should be replaced by '\\'.

Comment: Hello, can you help to explain: what is the meaning of * in \multirow{ 2}{*} ?

Answer (score 4):

For information, here is how you can construct that table with `{NiceTabular}` of [`nicematrix`](https://ctan.org/pkg/nicematrix).

In that environment, you merge cells both horizontally and vertically with the built-in command `\Block` and, with the key `hvlines`, all rules are drawn, excepted in those blocks.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
\centering
\begin{NiceTabular}{*{4}{c}*{7}{p{1cm}}}[hvlines]
A & B & C & D & \Block{1-*}{F}  \\ 
\Block{2-1}{1} & 0 & 6 & 230 & 35 & 40 & 55 & 25 & 40 & 35 & \\
& 1 & 5 & 195 & 25 & 50 & 35 & 40 & 45 &  &  \\ 
\end{NiceTabular}
\caption{A test caption}
\label{table2}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]

Comment: I think it would be better if you disclose yourself as the maintainer of the package based on your profile https://ctan.org/author/pantigny.

Answer (score 4):

An alternative solution with [`tabularray`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularray) package:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
\centering
\begin{tblr}{
  colspec={|c|c|c|c|p{1cm}p{1cm}p{1cm}p{1cm}p{1cm}p{1cm}p{1cm}|},
  hline{1,2,4},
  cell{1}{5} = {c=7}{c}, % multicolumn
  cell{2}{1} = {r=2}{m}, % multirow
}
A & B & C & D   & F  &    &    &    &    &    & \\
1 & 0 & 6 & 230 & 35 & 40 & 55 & 25 & 40 & 35 & \\
  & 1 & 5 & 195 & 25 & 50 & 35 & 40 & 45 &    & \\
\end{tblr}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]