# \multirow doesn't work in bengali

Tags: multirow

I use solution from [How to use \multirow](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/73283/how-to-use-multirow) but it doesn't work for me.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multido}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[a4paper,left=1cm,top=1cm,bottom=0cm,right=0cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[numerals=Devanagari]{bengali}
\setmainlanguage{bengali}
\setotherlanguage{english}
%\newfontfamily\englishfont[Scale=MatchLowercase]{Linux Biolinum O}
\newfontfamily\bengalifont[Script=Bengali]{Akaash}

\usepackage{pgffor}
\begin{document}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ccccc}
হলের নাম & জিম্মাদার সাথীর নাম & বিভাগ & সেশন & মোবাইল নাম্বার\\
\hline
\multirow{ 2}{*}{ফজলুল হক মুসলিম হল} & ভাই মোঃ শাহরিয়ার & & &\\
 & ভাই মোঃ রাজিন সালেহ & পদার্থ & ২০১৪-১৫ & 01724532286\\
অমর একুশে হল & ভাই মোঃ পারভেজ & কম্পিউটার বিজ্ঞান ও প্রকৌশল & ২০১৫-১৬ & 01854428475 \\
ডঃ মুহঃ শহীদুল্লাহ হল & ভাই মোঃ কবির & রসায়ন & ২০১৫-১৬ & 01515653835\\
কবি জসীম উদ্দিন হল & ভাই মোঃ & & &\\
বঙ্গবন্ধু হল &&&&\\
জিয়া হল &&&&\\
বিজয় একাত্তর হল &&&&\\
মাস্টার দ্যা সূর্যসেন হল & ভাই মোঃ ইব্রাহীম &&&\\
মহসিন হল &&&&\\
স্যার এ.ফ. রহমান হল &&&&\\
গিয়াস উদ্দিন আবাসিক এলাকা &&&&\\
উত্তর নীলক্ষেত &&&&\\
দক্ষিণ নীলক্ষেত &&&&\\
%&&&&\\
%&&&&\\
%&&&&\\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Except 1st column each column has two row for a cell in 1st row.

**Compilation error**

```
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex)))
(./hallJimmaderList.aux)
*geometry* driver: auto-detecting
*geometry* detected driver: xetex
ABD: EveryShipout initializing macros
! Undefined control sequence.
<recently read> \multirow 

l.18 \multirow
              { 2}{*}{ফজলুল হক মুসলিম হল} & ভাই মোঃ শাহরিয়ার & & &\\
?
```

Comment: you not load `multrow` package.

Comment: For future questions it would be good if you not just say "does not work" but add the error message you receive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nothing to do with bengali, you are simply missing `\usepackage{multirow}`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multido}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[a4paper,left=1cm,top=1cm,bottom=0cm,right=0cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{multirow}

\usepackage{pgffor}
\begin{document}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ccccc}
xx & xx & xx & xx & xxx\\
\hline
\multirow{ 2}{*}{xx} & xx & & &\\
 & xx & xx & xx & xx\\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]