# Custom Table row merge

Tags: tables

I can draw a simple table with non merged rows and columns. However, I want to draw a table in latex with some rows merged as shown below, any ideas on how to do it?

[image]

Comment: Please provide a minimal working example of what you tried. You can use the online tool [tablesgenerator](http://www.tablesgenerator.com/).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use \multirow](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/73283/how-to-use-multirow)

Answer (score 5):

I'd say that the image you posted is a *prime example* of a table whose "look" can be -- and should be! -- greatly improved by (a) omitting all vertical lines, (b) using fewer but well-spaced horizontal lines, and (c) aligning numbers, where appropriate, on their explicit or implicit decimal markers. As a byproduct of these improvements, the need to align some cell contents simply becomes a non-issue as long as you're used to reading a table's contents from left to right and from top to bottom.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,booktabs,siunitx}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{@{} l c c S[table-format=2.0] @{}}
\toprule
Load & R & Interval & {Result} \\
\midrule
99\% & 20 & 20\% &  9 \\
     &    & 40\% & 10 \\
\addlinespace % whitespace is a very effective visual separator
99\% & 30 & 20\% &  3 \\
     &    & 40\% &  5 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1 for advanced solution!

Answer (score 2):

In future please always provide an MWE (Minimal Working Example, a small but compilable document, which reproduce your problem), which show your problem. So, writing table from scratch (what is not fun), you can with proper use of the `multirow` package obtain the following result:

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=3.141592]{standalone}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
  \hline
Load    & R & Interval  & Result        \\
  \hline
\multirow{2}{*}{\SI{99}{\percent}}
        & \multirow{2}{*}{20}
            & \SI{20}{\percent} & 9     \\
  \cline{3-4}
        &   & \SI{20}{\percent} & 10    \\
  \hline
\multirow{2}{*}{\SI{99}{\percent}}
        & \multirow{2}{*}{30}
            & \SI{20}{\percent} & 3     \\
  \cline{3-4}
        &   & \SI{20}{\percent} & 4     \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```