# Multirow is not merging rows

Tags: tables, multirow

I am new to latex and I am trying to use multirow but it does not seem to work! It is not merging the rows and it's giving me a text when I define an empty cell for the merge. I also get an undefined control sequence

Here is the code:

```
\begin{table}[htb]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|l|}
    \hline
    \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{\rule{0pt}{14pt} \textbf{{\large Tactical Planning (SND)}}} \\ \hline
    \multirow{2}{|c|}{{}} & \textbf{Reference} & \qquad \qquad \textbf{Solution Approach} \\ \hline
                        & \multicolumn{2}{|c|} {\rule{0pt}{12pt} \textbf{{Dynamic SND with a variable network structure}}} \\ \hline
    Deterministic       & \cite{bai_optimisation_2018,crainic_modeling_2015,inghels_service_2016,li_design-balanced_2017} & Mixed-integer programming \\ \hline
    Stochastic & \cite{bai_stochastic_2014,hewitt_scheduled_2019,hoff_metaheuristic_2010,wang_stochastic_2019} & Two-stage stochastic programming \\ \hline
    & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\rule{0pt}{12pt} \textbf{{Dynamic SND with a given network structure}}} \\ \hline
    \multirow{2}{|c|}{Deterministic} & \cite{duan_freight_2019}& Mixed-integer nonlinear programming \\ \hline
                                    &\cite{heggen_intermodal_2019,sun_bi-objective_2019} & Mixed integer programming \\ \hline
    \multirow{3}{|c|}{Stochastic} &\cite{hui_airfreight_2014, meng_carrying_2015} & Two-stage stochastic programming \\ \hline
                                & \cite{hrusovsky_hybrid_2018,layeb_simulation-optimization_2018,zhang_synchromodal_2016} & Simualtion/simulation optimization \\ \hline
                                &\cite{demir_green_2016,sun_bi-objective_2019,zhao_chance-constrained_2018} & Mixed integer programming \\ \hline
    & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\rule{0pt}{12pt} \textbf{{Non-dynamic SND with a given network structure}}} \\ \hline
    Deterministic & \cite{katayama_combined_2019,tawfik_bilevel_2019,wang_hybrid_2019,zetina_profit-oriented_2019} & Mixed integer programming \\ \hline
    Stochastic & \cite{gao_uncertain_2016,rahmaniani_accelerating_2018,sun_stochastic_2017} & Two-stage stochastic programming\\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Tactical Planning Problems (SND) and Solution Methodologies}
    \label{tab:tacticalsnd}
\end{table}
```

This is the table I get
[image]

and this is the table I would like to have (this was on MS word):
[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE :) // Can you please add the rest of code required to: a) copy and run your code, b) contains your problem? Makes it easier for the rest of us. Thanks

Comment: Thank you! I added a couple of things and I hope they help.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE, @Maria Rodriguez. You seem to be using cite. Are all citations correct? Did you load the necessary packages? Are you using [multirow correct syntax](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/73283/140133)? Did you test the syntax by itself before writing a lot of stuff altogether, so that you know where and when things stopped working?

Comment: Please, read about [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/140133)s.

Comment: Thank you for your guidance FHZ!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this?

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{multirow}
    \usepackage{cite}

    \begin{document}

    \begin{table}[htb]
        \centering
        \begin{tabular}{|c|c|l|}
        \hline
        \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{\rule{0pt}{14pt} \textbf{{\large Tactical Planning (SND)}}} \\ \hline
        \multirow{2}{*}{{}} & \textbf{Reference} & \qquad \qquad \textbf{Solution Approach} \\ \hline
                            & \multicolumn{2}{|c|} {\rule{0pt}{12pt} \textbf{{Dynamic SND with a variable network structure}}} \\ \hline
        Deterministic & \cite{bai_optimisation_2018,crainic_modeling_2015,inghels_service_2016,li_design-balanced_2017} & Mixed-integer programming \\ \hline
        Stochastic & \cite{bai_stochastic_2014,hewitt_scheduled_2019,hoff_metaheuristic_2010,wang_stochastic_2019} & Two-stage stochastic programming \\ \hline
        & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\rule{0pt}{12pt} \textbf{{Dynamic SND with a given network structure}}} \\ \hline
        \multirow{2}{*}{Deterministic} & \cite{duan_freight_2019}& Mixed-integer nonlinear programming \\ \cline{2-3}
                                        &\cite{heggen_intermodal_2019,sun_bi-objective_2019} & Mixed integer programming \\ \hline
        \multirow{3}{*}{Stochastic} &\cite{hui_airfreight_2014, meng_carrying_2015} & Two-stage stochastic programming \\ \cline{2-3}
                                    & \cite{hrusovsky_hybrid_2018,layeb_simulation-optimization_2018,zhang_synchromodal_2016} & Simualtion/simulation optimization \\ \cline{2-3}
                                    &\cite{demir_green_2016,sun_bi-objective_2019,zhao_chance-constrained_2018} & Mixed integer programming \\ \hline
        & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\rule{0pt}{12pt} \textbf{{Non-dynamic SND with a given network structure}}} \\ \hline
        Deterministic & \cite{katayama_combined_2019,tawfik_bilevel_2019,wang_hybrid_2019,zetina_profit-oriented_2019} & Mixed integer programming \\ \hline
        Stochastic & \cite{gao_uncertain_2016,rahmaniani_accelerating_2018,sun_stochastic_2017} & Two-stage stochastic programming\\ \hline
        \end{tabular}
        \caption{Tactical Planning Problems (SND) and Solution Methodologies}
        \label{tab:tacticalsnd}
    \end{table}

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Or like this:

[image]

With `tabularray` package is simple:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}


\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[htb]
    \centering
\begin{tblr}{hlines, vlines,
              colspec = {ccl},
             row{1-3} = {font=\bfseries, c, bg=gray9}
             }
\SetCell[c=3]{font=\large\bfseries}  Tactical Planning (SND)
    &   &                                   \\
    &   Reference
        &   Solution Approach               \\
\SetCell[c=3]{font=\bfseries}    Dynamic SND with a variable network structure   
    &   &                                       \\
Deterministic
    &   \cite{bai_optimisation_2018,crainic_modeling_2015,inghels_service_2016,li_design-balanced_2017}
        &   Mixed-integer programming           \\ 
Stochastic
    & \cite{bai_stochastic_2014,hewitt_scheduled_2019,hoff_metaheuristic_2010,wang_stochastic_2019}
        & Two-stage stochastic programming      \\  
\SetCell[c=3]{font=\bfseries, bg=gray9}    Dynamic SND with a given network structure 
    &   &                                       \\  
\SetCell[r=2]{c}    Deterministic 
    & \cite{duan_freight_2019}
        & Mixed-integer nonlinear programming   \\  
    & \cite{heggen_intermodal_2019,sun_bi-objective_2019}
        & Mixed integer programming             \\  
\SetCell[r=3]{c}    Stochastic 
    & \cite{hui_airfreight_2014, meng_carrying_2015}
        & Two-stage stochastic programming      \\  
    & \cite{hrusovsky_hybrid_2018,layeb_simulation-optimization_2018,zhang_synchromodal_2016}
        & Simualtion/simulation optimization    \\
    &\cite{demir_green_2016,sun_bi-objective_2019,zhao_chance-constrained_2018}
        & Mixed integer programming             \\
\SetCell[c=3]{font=\bfseries, bg=gray9}    Non-dynamic SND with a given network structure
    &   &                                       \\
Deterministic
    & \cite{katayama_combined_2019,tawfik_bilevel_2019,wang_hybrid_2019,zetina_profit-oriented_2019}
        & Mixed integer programming             \\ 
    Stochastic & \cite{gao_uncertain_2016,rahmaniani_accelerating_2018,sun_stochastic_2017}
        & Two-stage stochastic programming      \\ 
    \end{tblr}
\caption{Tactical Planning Problems (SND) and Solution Methodologies}
    \label{tab:tacticalsnd}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```