# Merging cells of adjacent Rows

Tags: tables, formatting

Is it possible to merge rows like we can merge columns in Latex. I want a table like following.
[image]

Comment: with `multirow`?

Comment: As Zarko says. See e.g. http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/73283/how-to-use-multirow and http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/72945/how-to-merge-cells-vertically/72972#72972