# How to custom merge rows in Latex?

Tags: tables

I have tried different approaches however nothing works.

[image]

Any suggestions for creating a table with this layout? If I create 2 multirows (each with 2 rows-X and Y), I am not sure how to merge them for column c2 and c3. Thanks!

This is one example (spacing is all weird).

```
\usepackage{makecell}
\begin{table}[h]
\caption{Design of Experiment1} % title name of the table
\centering % centering table
\begin{tabular}{c c c c} % creating 4 columns
\hline\hline % inserting double-line
\\ [0.5ex]
Group &Training &Reversal &Notation
\\ [0.1ex]
\hline % inserts single-line
\\ [0.5ex]
% 1st row
 & &  & WT L1(+||-)  \\[1ex]
% 2nd row row
 \raisebox{1.5ex}{WT} & &  & WT L2(-||+)  \\[1ex]
% 3rd row
 & &  & HET L1(+||-)  \\[1ex]
% 4th row
 \raisebox{1.5ex}{HET} & \raisebox{2ex} {\makecell{L1 reinforced  (L+) \\ L2 
 non-reinforced (L-)}} & \raisebox{2ex}{\makecell{L1 non-reinforced (L-) \\ 
 L2 reinforced (L+)}}   & WT L2(-||+)\\[1ex]

\hline % inserts single-line
\end{tabular}
\label{tab:PPer}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to merge cells vertically](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/72945/how-to-merge-cells-vertically)

Comment: It is not a duplicate, because what I am not able to do is merge after creating multirow. I can create 2 multirows (each with 2 rows- for X and Y), however I am not sure how to merge them in the 2nd and 3rd column.

Comment: @AdelaIliescu: In this case, please show a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) of what you tried so far. This way it is much easier to help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array, multirow, boldline}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!h]
  \centering\sffamily\setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}
  \begin{tabular}{V{2.5}*{3}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{1cm}|}>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{1cm}V{2.5}}
\hlineB{2.5}
        c1 &c2 & c3 & c4 \\
\hlineB{2}
\multirow{2}{*}{X} & & & a\\
 & \multirow{2}{*}{XY}& \multirow{2}{*}{YZ} & b \\
 \cline{1-1}\cline{4-4}
\multirow{2}{*}{Y} & & & c \\
 & & & d \\
 \hlineB{2.5}
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @AdelaIliescu: I don't quite understand what should  be the multirows of the 2nd and 3rd columns

Comment: It's a design table for an experiment. X and Y are two groups that receive the same treatment in phase c2 and c3 but not c4.