# Merging table rows instead of splitting them?

Tags: tables, multicolumn

I have a table that looks like this:

```
| COLUMN A | COLUMN B | COLUMN C | COLUMN D |
|-------------------------------------------|
|    0     |    A     |   100    |   150    |
|    1     |    B     |   100    |   150    |
|    2     |    C     |   200    |   250    |
|    3     |    D     |   200    |   250    |
```

As you can see, the values in columns A and B are different each row, but columns C and D only change every other row. It would be useful to merge only columns C and D so that they are "shared" between two rows, while columns A and B work as normal. Something like this, but without the blank cells in A and B:

```
| COLUMN A | COLUMN B | COLUMN C | COLUMN D |
|-------------------------------------------|
|    0     |    A     |          |          |
|          |          |   100    |   150    |
|    1     |    B     |          |          |
|    2     |    C     |          |          |
|          |          |   200    |   250    |
|    3     |    D     |          |          |
```

Essentially, it would be the inverse of [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/72945/how-to-merge-cells-vertically), which merges the first column in the table and splits subsequent columns.

Comment: The solution is the same, simply use `\multirow` in the column you wish.

Comment: the `multirow` package  is your friend :-).

Comment: Also, please, post a minimal code so we don't need to type everything for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|*{4}{c|}}
    \hline
A   &   B   &   C   &   D   \\
    \hline
0   &   A   & \multirow{2}{*}{100}  &   \multirow{2}{*}{150}  \\
1   &   B   &                       &                       \\
0   &   A   & \multirow{2}{*}{100}  &   \multirow{2}{*}{150}  \\
1   &   B   &                       &                       \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, this works perfectly! May I ask why you put braces around the asterisk in the first multirow but not the second?

Comment: @klasdfjasdf, i simply forgot. it works with curly braces and without them. however. it is better to use them. i will corrected asap.